# "-XX:+PrintHeapAtGC" Why I can't find this jvm args from oracle jdk docs?

Tags: jvm

I use jdk8. recently I try to understand jvm gc, we can use that args on jdk8, however I can't get any description about "-XX:+PrintHeapAtGC" on oracle jdk8 docs, even jdk7.

jvm ars' docs:
jdk8 : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html
jdk7 : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

Comment: `-XX` are non-standard options. They are [not stable and are subject to change without notice](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html).

Comment: btw. VM Options Explorer can be useful: https://chriswhocodes.com/hotspot_options_jdk8.html

Answer (score -1):

the same as -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation, -XX:+NumberOfGCLogFiles, -XX:+GCLogFileSize=n